# i can't open http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx and Microsoft sites in my all browsers

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have a strange issue that in my system i can open all sites except Microsoft sites ,when try to open this sites it showing error like

```
          Oops! Google Chrome could not find msdn.microsoft.com
          Suggestions:
          Access a cached copy of msdn.­microsoft.­com/­en-­us/­magazine/­dd315413.­aspx
          Go to microsoft.­com
          Search on Google
```

why i can't open this siets please any body knows help me...

Comment: do you use any antivirus if then which check firewall setting if it is in the shaed environment chheck if it's blocked from firewall also check antivirus blocked sites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if this is happening in all your browsers, you are likely infected with a virus that is blocking the site from your computer.  here's one possible place to start looking for a solution: http://www.secureworks.com/research/threats/downadup-removal/

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response i will try these Removal sites ....

Comment: sure thing! good luck getting things taken care of. :)

Answer (score 1):

Open Windows Services (Go to `Start`->`Run`, type `services.msc` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>). Scroll down and find the `DNS Client` service. Right-click on it and click **Restart**. Now, try visiting the website